# Add varied number of parameters to properties file

Tags: java, internationalization

suppose we are trying to print out a list of names of children that go to school using a properties file and the list of names varies in size:

```java
List<String> names = newArrayList<>("john", "sarah", "george");
```

the properties file is:

```
key.print.names = "{0} all go to {1} school"
```

I want an output like:

> john, sarah, and george all go to MLK school

Keep in mind the list of names will change. How can that be done with a properties file?

Comment: Well, first you have to figure out how to delimit a list in the targeted language, then you can fill out the unknowns.

Comment: I didn't understand: in the properties file, do you have only  the string  or also the name of the children?

Comment: Use a combination of the properties file and code.  Only use the properties file for the static language.  Loop through the names.  Then append the string from the properties file.

Comment: so im guessing the solution is to create a string from the arraylist and pass it into the first parameter of the property? I was hoping there would be a more elegeant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use

```
MessageFormat.format(property.getString("key.print.names"),String.join(",",names),schoolName);
```

EDIT: how to add and before last name:

```
String listOfNames = String.join(" and ",
                        Arrays.asList(
                            String.join(",", names.subList(0, names.size() - 1)), 
                            names.get(names.size() - 1)
                        )
                     );
MessageFormat.format(property.getString("key.print.names"),listOfNames,schoolName);
```

EDIT: as suggested in the comment, if you want a sort of localization you can use a property for the conjunction and the snippet will become:

```
String listOfNames = String.join(new StringBuilder(" ")              
                                .append(property.getString("key.conjunction.en"))
                                .append(" ").toString(),
                        Arrays.asList(
                            String.join(",", names.subList(0, names.size() - 1)), 
                            names.get(names.size() - 1)
                        )
                     );
MessageFormat.format(property.getString("key.print.names"),listOfNames,schoolName);
```

In a more complex scenario (web application) you can use `ResourceBoundle`, more info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) and [here](https://mkyong.com/java/java-resourcebundle-example/)

Comment: That prints out "john, sarah, george go to MLK school". Is it possible to add the "and" before the last name?

Comment: Isn't "and" language-dependent? If you want localization, you need to commit 100%. That would be another config property.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, sure, like "go to" and "school"

Comment: @Renato no, this is the English BASE form: `""{0} all go to {1} school""`. Inside `{0}`, you need to not only join the names, but also grab a conjunction from the config as well. Your example has a hard-coded "and".

Comment: @Mr.Polywhilr, exactly I mean the same: the localization isn't part of question, in any case I'm agree with you, in the simplest way he needs the key.conjunction property